# asp web api json serialization returns private properties

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, wsdl

I have a Web api controller class 
and i call a method on a proxy class generated from a WSDL from the web api controller,
and i return an object of type defined in the WSDL proxy class.

but the xml/json returned contains the private members of the proxy class

the private members are

```
    private string companyField;

    private string soldBPField;

    private string fromDateField;

    private string toDateField;

    private long succStatusField;
```

and the xml returned is :

```
<companyField>700</companyField>
<soldBPField>999000353</soldBPField>
<fromDateField>01-01-2012</fromDateField>
<toDateField>01-01-2013</toDateField>
```

the json returned is also similar

I changed the xml formatter in the global.asax as follows:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

this changed the XML returned to:

```
<company>700</company>
<soldBP>999000353</soldBP>
<fromDateField>01-01-2012</fromDate>
<toDate>01-01-2013</toDate>
```

but the json returned still contains the name of the private variables

**can any one help me with this**

Comment: How are you generating a WSDL with private properties? Only public properties are normally exported in the WSDL.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't public properties that expose those fields somewhere? Perhaps it's a `partial` class and another `partial` is exposing them? Does Intellisense show that those properties exist?

Comment: there are public properties that expose those private properties for eg: property companyField is exposed through public property company which has a getter and setter pointing to company.C#  intellisense does not show the private property companyField.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are your types marked as `[Serializable]`? Serializable means that the serializer should serialize all fields - private or public. Try to remove `Serializable` or else use this line to stop the JSON formatter from recognizing the attribute:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Comment: thanks @Youssef Moussaoui
the above setting helped :can you explain what was going wrong

Comment: Removing serializable works and so does setting the config. It would be nice to know the reason why the config does what it does and also know if there are any negative consequences to changing the config this way.

Comment: I had this exact issue with a web api that consumed an older soap service and exposed the private class variables instead of the public attributes. This line fixed that :)